# Is nxml-mode vulnerable to the billion laughs attack?

Tags: nxml

I was asked this by a friend, and I couldn't find any information about whether this vulnerability exists in nxml-mode as current or not. I specifically mean [this billion laughs attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion_laughs).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well that's incredibly easy to test, right?

Fire up a new Emacs instance, open a new XML file, paste in the code, see whether Emacs explodes.

(Spoiler: Yes, it does.)

Comment: FWIW, Emacs' pure Emacs Lisp XML parser (`xml-parse-region`) does so as well, whereas libxml (`libxml-parse-region`) refuses to parse it and silently fails with `nil`.

Comment: I would expect anything to be vulnerable to this unless it's been hardened against it.  libxml is one of these exceptions.